# No performance gain with SIMD 3D vector for ray tracer

Tags: c++, comparative-review, x86, simd, raytracing

I wrote two versions of vector class for my ray tracer. Non-SIMD version and SIMD version. You can find the code below. I want to ask what things should I keep in mind to get max performance with SIMD. I am not getting any performance gain with this. I turned off compiler optimizations and still no results.

```
#ifndef INC_VEC4_H
#define INC_VEC4_H

#define USE_SSE

#ifndef USE_SSE

#include<iostream>
#include<cassert>


class vec4
{
public:

    union {
        struct {    float x, y, z,w; };
        struct {    float r, g, b,a; };
    };

    //normalised directions
    static vec4 UP;
    static vec4 DOWN;
    static vec4 ZERO;
    static vec4 LEFT;
    static vec4 RIGHT;
    static vec4 FORWARD;
    static vec4 BACKWARD;

  //construction
    vec4();
  explicit vec4(float x , float y, float z ,float w = 1.0f) ;
  explicit vec4(float n);
  vec4(const vec4& other);
  vec4& operator = (const vec4& other);
  //destruction
  ~vec4();


  //vec4-vec4 arithmetic operations
  inline vec4 operator + (const vec4& other) const{
    return vec4( x+other.x,
      y + other.y,
      z + other.z);
  }
  inline vec4 operator - (const vec4& other) const {
    return vec4(x - other.x,
      y - other.y,
      z - other.z);
  }

  //vec4-vec4 arithmetic operations
  inline void operator += (const vec4& other) {
      x += other.x;
      y += other.y;
      z += other.z;
  }


  inline vec4 operator * (const vec4& other) const {
    return vec4(x*other.x,
      y*other.y,
      z*other.z);
  }
  inline vec4 operator / (const vec4& other) const {
    assert((int)other.x!=0 && (int)other.y!=0 && (int)other.z!=0);
    return vec4(x / other.x,
      y / other.y,
      z / other.z);
  }
  inline void operator *= (const vec4& other) {
    x *= other.x;
    y *= other.y;
    z *= other.z;
  }
  inline void operator /= (const vec4& other) {
     x /= other.x;
     y /= other.y;
     z /= other.z;
  }
  //vec4-scalar * & /

  inline vec4 operator / (float scalar) const {
    assert(scalar>0.00000f);
    return vec4(x / scalar, y / scalar, z/scalar);
  }
  inline void operator *= (float scalar) {
    x *= scalar; 
    y *= scalar; 
    z *= scalar;
  }
  inline void operator /= (float scalar) {
    assert(scalar>0.00000000f);
    x /= scalar; 
    y /= scalar; 
    z /= scalar;
  }

  inline vec4 normalize() const {
    vec4 v;
    v.x = x / length();
    v.y = y / length();
    v.z = z / length();
    return v;
  }


  inline float length() const{
    return (sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z)));
  }


  inline float squared_length() const {
    return x * x + y * y + z * z;
  }

  inline void make_it_unit() {

    x /= length();
    y /= length();
    z /= length();

  }

  inline vec4& make_itzero() {
    x = y = z = 0;
    return *this;
  }

  inline float dot(const vec4& other) const {
    return ((x*other.x)+(y*other.y)+(z*other.z));
  }

  inline vec4 cross(const vec4& other) const {
    return vec4(
    y*other.z+z*other.y,
      z*other.x+x*other.z,
      x*other.y+y*other.x
    );
  }

  //checks 
  bool check_ifzero() const{
    //typecasting the floats to int since its hard to compare two floats against each other
    bool result = (((int)x) == 0 && ((int)y) == 0 && ((int)z) == 0);
    return result;
  }
  //IO
  friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& cout, const vec4& other);
};

//non-member inline operators
inline vec4 operator * (const vec4& v,float scalar) {
  return vec4(v.x * scalar, v.y * scalar, v.z * scalar);
}

inline vec4 operator * (float scalar, const vec4& v) {
  return vec4(v.x * scalar, v.y * scalar, v.z * scalar);
}

inline float dot(const vec4& v1, const vec4& v2) {
  return (v1.x*v2.x + v1.y*v2.y+v1.z*v2.z);
}

#else

#include<nmmintrin.h>

_declspec(align(16))
struct vec4
{
    union {
        __m128 vec;
        struct { float x, y, z, w; };
        struct { float r, g, b, a; };
    };

    //normalised directions
    static vec4 UP;
    static vec4 DOWN;
    static vec4 ZERO;
    static vec4 LEFT;
    static vec4 RIGHT;
    static vec4 FORWARD;
    static vec4 BACKWARD;

    //construction
    vec4();
    vec4(float x, float y, float z, float w = 1.0f);
    explicit vec4(float n);
    vec4(const vec4& other);
    vec4& operator = (const vec4& other);
    //destruction
    ~vec4();

    inline float dot(const vec4& other)
    {
        __m128 dotResult = _mm_dp_ps(vec, other.vec, 0x7F);
        float result;
        _mm_store_ss(&result, dotResult);
        return result;
    }

    inline void make_it_unit()
    {
        __m128 selfDot = _mm_dp_ps(vec, vec, 0x7F);
        __m128 sqrtResult = _mm_rsqrt_ps(selfDot);
        vec = _mm_mul_ps(vec, sqrtResult);
    }

    inline vec4 normalize()
    {
        vec4 result;
        __m128 selfDot = _mm_dp_ps(vec, vec, 0x7F);
        __m128 sqrtResult = _mm_rsqrt_ps(selfDot);
        result.vec = _mm_mul_ps(vec, sqrtResult);
        return result;
    }

    inline float length()
    {
        __m128 selfDot = _mm_dp_ps(vec, vec, 0x7F);
        __m128 sqrtResult = _mm_sqrt_ps(selfDot);
        float result;
        _mm_store_ss(&result, sqrtResult);
        return result;
    }

    //vec4-vec4 arithmetic operations
    inline vec4 operator + (const vec4& other) const {
        vec4 result;
        result.vec = _mm_add_ps(vec, other.vec);
        return result;
    }
    inline vec4 operator - (const vec4& other) const {
        vec4 result;
        result.vec = _mm_sub_ps(vec, other.vec);
        return result;
    }

    //vec4-vec4 arithmetic operations
    inline void operator += (const vec4& other) {
        vec = _mm_add_ps(vec, other.vec);
    }


    inline vec4 operator * (const vec4& other) const {
        vec4 result;
        result.vec = _mm_mul_ps(vec, other.vec);
        return result;
    }
    inline vec4 operator / (const vec4& other) const {
        vec4 result;
        result.vec = _mm_div_ps(vec, other.vec);
        return result;
    }
    inline void operator *= (const vec4& other) {
        vec = _mm_mul_ps(vec, other.vec);
    }
    inline void operator /= (const vec4& other) {
        vec = _mm_div_ps(vec, other.vec);
    }
    //vec4-scalar * & /

    inline vec4 operator / (float scalar) const {
        vec4 result;
        __m128 _scalar = _mm_set_ps(scalar, scalar, scalar, scalar);
        result.vec = _mm_div_ps(vec, _scalar);
        return result;
    }
    inline void operator *= (float scalar) {
        __m128 _scalar = _mm_set_ps(scalar, scalar, scalar, scalar);
        vec = _mm_mul_ps(vec, _scalar);
    }
    inline void operator /= (float scalar) {
        __m128 _scalar = _mm_set_ps(scalar, scalar, scalar, scalar);
        vec = _mm_div_ps(vec, _scalar);
    }



    inline float squared_length() const {
        float result;
        __m128 dotResult = _mm_dp_ps(vec, vec, 0x7F);
        _mm_store_ss(&result, dotResult);
        return result;
    }

    inline vec4& make_itzero() {
        vec = _mm_set_ps(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }


    inline vec4 cross(const vec4& other) const {
        vec4 result;
        result.vec = _mm_sub_ps(
            _mm_mul_ps(_mm_shuffle_ps(vec, vec, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 0, 2, 1)), _mm_shuffle_ps(other.vec, other.vec, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 0, 2))),
            _mm_mul_ps(_mm_shuffle_ps(vec, vec, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 1, 0, 2)), _mm_shuffle_ps(other.vec, other.vec, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 0, 2, 1)))
        );
        return result;
    }

    //checks 
    bool check_ifzero() const {

    }
};

//non-member inline operators
inline vec4 operator * (const vec4& v, float scalar) {
    vec4 result;
    __m128 _scalar = _mm_set_ps(scalar, scalar, scalar, scalar);
    result.vec = _mm_mul_ps(v.vec, _scalar);
    return result;
}

inline vec4 operator * (float scalar, const vec4& v) {
    vec4 result;
    __m128 _scalar = _mm_set_ps(scalar, scalar, scalar, scalar);
    result.vec = _mm_mul_ps(v.vec, _scalar);
    return result;
}

inline float dot(const vec4& v1, const vec4& v2) {
    __m128 dotResult = _mm_dp_ps(v1.vec, v2.vec, 0x7F);
    float result;
    _mm_store_ss(&result, dotResult);
    return result;
}


#endif

#endif
```

Comment: What task does this code accomplish? Please tell us, and also make that the title of the question via [edit]. Maybe you missed the placeholder on the title element: "_State the task that your code accomplishes. Make your title distinctive._". Also from  [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask): "_State what your code does in your title, not your main concerns about it._".

Comment: I see a class with lots of operators, but no main program. What did you actually measure to conclude that you are *“not getting any performance gain with this”?*

Comment: Is your `#define USE_SSE` order swapped?

Comment: "1 SIMD vector == 1 math vector" implementations have inherent performance issues (dot product is forced to be inefficient). Fixing that is very non-local and basically restructures the whole program. It's not so much an issue with the code shown here, but an issue with the entire approach implied by it.